# How do I used Knockout's "hasfocus" Click-to-Edit (Example 2) on a page that has multiple field:value pairs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How do I used [Knockout's "hasfocus" binding in Click-to-Edit (Example 2)](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html) on a page that has multiple field:value pairs? I have a page for View Customer Details, and I want to have this capability to edit upon double click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of PersonViewModels and foreach loop them in the view. To reuse the example on the knockout page the code could look like this:

```
    (function () {
        function PersonViewModel(name) {
            // Data
            this.name = ko.observable(name);
            this.editing = ko.observable(false);

            // Behaviors
            this.edit = function() { this.editing(true) }
        }

        function ViewModel(personModels) {
            this.persons = ko.observableArray(personModels);
        }

        var personModels = [
            new PersonViewModel('Bert'),
            new PersonViewModel('James'),
            new PersonViewModel('Eddy')
        ];

        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(personModels));
    })();
```

And the view:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: persons">
    <p>
        Name: 
        <b data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: name, click: edit">&nbsp;</b>
        <input data-bind="visible: editing, value: name, hasfocus: editing" />
    </p>
    <p><em>Click the name to edit it; click elsewhere to apply changes.</em></p>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/danne567/gTHpu/